# 2 Column layout fluid adjustable width

Tags: html, css

I have searched for a solution to this for a couple of days now and can not seem to find a answer. What I am trying to achieve is a 2 column layout where the left column is fluid based on the browsers width and the right column width based on its contents.

The right column can not have a fixed width since some of the content is generated from a database and the widths can vary. I think the solution has something to deal with display: inline-block but can not seem to get it right. When the contents of the left column pushes the width of the column wider than the space available the right column jumps to another line and does not stay inline.

*We also need to stay away from any javascript because some of the users will have it disabled.*

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='left'> 
      this is some really long text that takes up a lot of room since it is so long
   </div>
   <div id='right'>
      <a>this is a link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
   width: 100%;
   background: red;
}

#left{
   display: inline-block;
   background: green;
}

#right{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 15px;
   background: yellow;
}

#right a{
   padding: 5px 20px;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using flexbox:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It's really nice tool. I suppose it could help.

Comment: That might be a solution, how is the cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: Really good, every new browser has it, and some old need -webkit-.
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

After researching answers I actually ran into a some code and noticed a possible answer which seems to work! I was very close with my original code but was wrong about the display: inline-block being the key. The answer was actually a slight change with the CSS but most importantly the order of my HTML.

The answer was putting the right column **BEFORE** the left. This way the browser can calculate what it thinks is the "Remaining" width of the left column but we display it backwards. In other words we are laying out the columns first the right which is calculated from the width of the children then letting the browser calculate the rest of the width for the left column. Then in the CSS we switch the locations of the left and right columns to display how we want.

Here is the working code:

CSS:

```
    html,
    body{
        height: 100%;
    }

    #container{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
    }

    #left{
        width: auto;
        background: green;
    }

    #rightWrapper{
        float: right;
        height: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }

    #right{
        margin: 15px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    #right a{
        padding: 5px 20px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id='container'>
       <div id='rightWrapper'>
           <div id='right'>
              <a>this is a link that grows</a>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div id='left'>
          this is some really long text that takes up a lot of room since it is so long ........
       </div>
   </div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**
While working on a entirely different problem and stumbled upon this solution that is much less complicated. Basically just turn the outer  into a table and the inner 's to a a table-cell. If no height is given full height is assumed and set width of column to something smaller than you need. Here is a sample:

CSS:

```
    #container{
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        background: red;
    }

    #left{
        display: table-cell;
        background: green;
    }

    #right{
        display: table-cell;
        width: 50px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    #right a{
        padding: 5px 20px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id='container'>
       <div id='left'>
          this is some really long text that takes up a lot of room since it is so long ........
       </div>
       <div id='right'>
          <a>this is a link that grows</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```